# PyQt5: Avoid wavy tab when scrolling

Tags: python, pyqt5

As you can see in the image, when I scroll to the right of the TabWidget, the left tab appears wavy.
How can I remove the wavy?
The button at the top left should always appear and represent a kind of home button. However, I want it to look exactly like the tabs in terms of style. That's why I want the wavy to go away.

[image: Wavy Tab]

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTabWidget, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

# Subclass QMainWindow to customize your application's main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.setStyleSheet(
"QTabBar::tab:left, QTabBar::tab:right {\n"
"    height: 100px;\n"
"    margin-bottom: 50px;\n"
"cursor: pointer;\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::tab {\n"
"  background: rgb(230, 230, 230); \n"
"  border: 1px solid lightgray; \n"
"  padding: 15px;\n"
"  background: gray;\n"
"  color: white;\n"
"  padding: 10px;\n"
"} \n"
"\n"
"QTabBar::tab:selected { \n"
"  background: rgb(245, 245, 245); \n"
"  margin-bottom: -1px; \n"
"    background: green;\n"
"}\n"
"QTabBar::scroller { /* the width of the scroll buttons */\n"
"    width: 100px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
)
        tabs.setCornerWidget(QPushButton("Button"), Qt.TopLeftCorner)
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 0")
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 1")
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 2")
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 3")
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 4")
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), QIcon(), "Test 5")

        # Set the central widget of the Window.
        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```